# Encountering an error decoupling tasks and vars from playbooks via roles

Tags: variables, ansible, task, roles, ansible-lint

To start, I have a basic ansible directory structure for roles.

In the [ansible] directory:

```
- inventory
- playbook.yml
- [roles]
    - [gui_utils]
        - [defaults]
            - main.yml
        - [files]
            - main.yml
        - [handlers]
            - main.yml
        - [library]
            - my_module.py
        - [meta]
            - main.yml
        - [tasks]
            - main.yml
        - [templates]
            - main.yml
        - [vars]
            - main.yml
```

The only files that contain any relevant data are:

- `ansible/inventory`

```
[all]
#
[prep]
ansible-prep ansible_connection=local ansible_host=localhost
```

- `ansible/playbook.yml`

```
 - hosts: prep
   tasks:
      - name: "Update cache if older than 3600 seconds"
        ansible.builtin.apt:
           update_cache: yes
           cache_valid_time: 3600
           update_cache_retries: 10
           update_cache_retry_max_delay: 18

      - name: "Import and run task to install 'gui_utils'".
        import_tasks: roles/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml
```

- `ansible/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml`

```
 - tasks:
      - name: "Load gui_utils_list variable"
        include_vars: "{{ role_path }}/vars/main.yml"

      - name: "Install GUI utility packages"
        ansible.builtin.apt:
           name: "{{ gui_utils_list }}"
           state: present
```

- `ansible/gui_utils/vars/main.yml`

```
gui_utils_list:
   - notepadqq
   - redshift
```

Executing `ansible-lint ansible/playbook.yml` returns the following error.

```
root@ansible-prep:/home/user/Desktop/ansible-project# ansible-lint ansible/playbook.yml
CRITICAL Couldn't parse task at /home/user/Desktop/ansible-project/ansible/roles/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml:4 (couldn't resolve module/action 'tasks'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.)
{ 'tasks': [ { '__file__': '/home/user/Desktop/ansible-project/ansible/roles/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml',
               '__line__': 16,
               'include_vars': '{{ role_path }}/vars/main.yml',
               'name': 'Load gui_utils_list variable'},
             { '__file__': '/home/user/Desktop/ansible-project/ansible/roles/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml',
               '__line__': 19,
               'ansible.builtin.apt': { '__file__': '/home/user/Desktop/ansible-project/ansible/roles/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml',
                                        '__line__': 21,
                                        'name': '{{ gui_utils_list }}',
                                        'state': 'present'},
               'name': 'Install GUI utility packages'}]}
root@ansible-prep:/home/user/Desktop/ansible-project#
```

Unfortunately, this is not helping me to resolve the issue.  `ansible-lint ansible/roles/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml` returns without any errors and, if I remove the `- name` and `import_tasks` lines from `ansible/playbook.yml`, `ansible-lint ansible/playbook.yml` also returns no errors.  At this point, I think my error is in the last two lines of `ansible/playbook.yml` but I do not know what is wrong, specifically, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **"*gui_utils/tasks/main.yml:4 (couldn't resolve module/action 'tasks'.*"**

A: Remove the keyword *tasks* from ansible/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml. The task *import_tasks* is already in the *tasks* section of the playbook

```yaml
---
- name: "Load gui_utils_list variable"
  include_vars: "{{ role_path }}/vars/main.yml"

- name: "Install GUI utility packages"
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name: "{{ gui_utils_list }}"
    state: present
```

---

**[import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-import-role-import-a-role-into-a-play) instead of import_tasks**

The code will be simpler with *import_role* instead of with *import_tasks*. Running *tasks/main.yml* is the [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from)

```yaml
      - name: "Import role gui_utils."
        import_role:
          name: gui_utils
```

This way you can also omit the task *"Load gui_utils_list variable"* from ansible/gui_utils/tasks/main.yml. The *vars/main.yml* is read by [default](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#parameter-vars_from) in the role too. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

```yaml
---
- name: "Install GUI utility packages"
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name: "{{ gui_utils_list }}"
    state: present
```

The only difference is that *import_role* will make available other role's artifacts (defaults, handlers, ...) to the play. But, this is what the roles are for. See [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#notes).

Comment: Thank you.  I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how the directory structure loads for roles and how to properly access roles.